# Die Toss and Coin Flip Conditional Probability Distribution

Tags: probability

Toss a die two times. Let $X$ be the the numbers of twos. Then, flip a coin $X$ times. Let $Y$ be the number of tails.

I am trying to find the pdf.

My work so far:

I know that the number of twos can be represented by $ n \choose k$$\left(\theta\right)^{k}\left(1-\theta\right)^{n-k}$ where $n=2$ and $\theta=\frac{1}{6}$.

So would the pdf look something like this $f\left(Y|X\right)$ $=f\left(Y=\frac{X}{2}|X ={n \choose k} \left(\theta\right)^{k}\left(1-\theta\right)^{n-k}
\right)$
?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why is $\theta=\frac{1}{6}$ ?

Comment: That was a typo that I made. My mistake.

Comment: wouldn't be more logical to set $n=2$ and $\theta=\frac{1}{6}$ in the main equation instead of mentioning them on the side since we are always going to find the number of twos in two tosses, your main equation is more general so why not set it to be more specific to your problem?> just a suggestion

Comment: I forgot to change both equations. My apologies again.

Comment: Also, mind explaining why you have $Y=\frac{X}{2}$? I am far from being an expert but this doesn't seem right to me, I might be wrong.

Comment: That is the part that is giving me the most trouble. My logic is that the odds of getting heads or tails on any given coin toss is $\frac{1}{2}$. I am probably wrong.

Comment: One more thing, doesn't your equation give the probability of getting a certain number of twos where $k$ is the number of twos and not the actual number?

Comment: That is a good point . . . you are right. Do you have any suggestions on what a batter approach would be?

Comment: well, again I AM NOT an expert, but the first thought on my mind would be to use the expected value of a binomial distribution which is equal to $np$ where $p$ is the probability of getting a two in one trial so $\frac{1}{6}$ and $n$ is the number of dice rolls

Comment: So something like this: $f\left(Y|X\right)=\left(\frac{n}{6}|\frac{X}{2}\right)$?